# Bluetooth pairing not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am struggling through one of issue related to Bluetooth pairing in my device(Samsung Galaxy S6). I have list-view, where i am populating my BLE device names as in below image [image]

When user will click on any BLE it should get pair with that BLE. My code effort are below:

1. For calling Broadcast receiver(to pupulate BLEs name)

   ```
   // Quick permission check
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   int permissionCheck = getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
   permissionCheck += getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
   if (permissionCheck != 0) {

   this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
   }
   }

   getActivity().registerReceiver(FoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
   getActivity().registerReceiver(FoundReceiver, filter);

   mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
   ```

   1. For populating List of BLEs code is below which is working fine.

      ```
      private final BroadcastReceiver FoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      String action = intent.getAction();

      // When discovery finds a new device
      if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
          // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
          BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
          if (!bleName.contains(device)) {
              if(device.getName() != null){
                  bleName.add(device.getName());
              }
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name: " + device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              bedListADPT = new BleList(context, bleName);
              listView.setAdapter(bedListADPT);
              if(!dvcNameBle.containsKey(device.getName())) {
                  dvcNameBle.put(device.getName(), device);
              }
              bedListADPT.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

      }
      // When discovery cycle finished
      if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
          if (bleName == null || bleName.isEmpty()) {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
      }
      };
      ```

Now when user will click on list item it should get pair with that BLE name.

2. Click event for List item

   ```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                           int position, long arg3) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),bedListADPT.getItem(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");

      /**
        * Registering a new BTBroadcast receiver from the Main Activity context
        * with pairing request event
        */
       selectedDevice = bedListADPT.getItem(position).toString();
       getActivity().registerReceiver(new PairingRequest(dvcNameBle,selectedDevice), filter);
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+dvcNameBle.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
   });
   ```

And Broadcast receiver is below to get Pair with BLE

```
public  class PairingRequest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static HashMap<String, BluetoothDevice> mdvcNameBle = new HashMap<String, BluetoothDevice>();
    private static String mselectedDevice = "";
    public PairingRequest() {
        super();
    }

    public PairingRequest(HashMap<String, BluetoothDevice> dvcNameBle, String mselectedDevice){
        super();
        this.mdvcNameBle = dvcNameBle;
        this.mselectedDevice = mselectedDevice;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST")) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = mdvcNameBle.get(mselectedDevice);

                int pin=intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
                //the pin in case you need to accept for an specific pin
                Log.d("PIN", " " + intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY",0));
                //maybe you look for a name or address
                Log.d("Bonded", device.getName());
                byte[] pinBytes;
                pinBytes = (""+pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                device.setPin(pinBytes);
                //setPairing confirmation if neeeded
                device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside manifest file i have declared Broadcast receiver and required permissions for application

```
<receiver android:name=".PairingRequest">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  android:label="BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

When i am calling

> PairingRequest

nothing is happening; that means no exception no pairing.

Any help will be really appreciable. Please help me get rid this issue.

Comment: I think that you have a permission problem. From Android 6.0 you have to request for permission on runtime. Look at this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Ok. Sure i will check it and get back to you.

Comment: Any comments or suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
        throws Exception {
    Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
    Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
    Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
    return returnValue.booleanValue();
}
```

If above code is not working in API 23, Then do quick check for Android Permissions.

```
    // Quick permission check
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int permissionCheck = getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        permissionCheck += getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if (permissionCheck != 0) {

            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
        }
    }
```